# StdOut class not found

Tags: java

I'm using netbeans 8.0.1 to write, compile and run my code buy I can't seem to find the "standard Libraries" like StdOut and StdStats that are referred examples that I find.

Example:

```
https://github.com/merwan/algs4/blob/master/percolation/src/PercolationStats.java
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdStats.html
```

I can use System.out.println and the like to print but the StdOut class isn't found.

Anyone else having the same issue and if so, how does one rectify it?

Comment: These are not standard classes. Like princeton.edu created their StdStats and provide source for it. If you want to use these classes - compile them and add to your classpath.

Comment: As explained in the second link, those classes were written by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne for a Java textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you standard library as a part of the princeton course .It also gives details of adding it 
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Comment: So I should be adding that jar to the project?

Comment: @paullb Only if you have good reason to use it rather than the available functionality in the Java standard library.

Comment: If you using some class in that library or some other class which uses that library then you should include that in your classpath.

Comment: Upon rereading the assignment, it looks like I should include it. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

The term "stdout" is just a shortening of the phrase "standard output". It's a language-agnostic term, but in Java it usually just refers to `System.out`. In other words, if you're looking for a `StdOut` class in the standard library, you won't find one, because it's not the name of a standard Java class.

Comment: I don't think that's right. I just added some example URLs to the question

Comment: @paullb See edit. It's quite possible for it to be the name of the class (I could easily create a `StdOut` class in about five seconds), but it's not the name of a class *in the standard Java library*.